Allow pinning widgets from other communities
I think it would be nice (and encourage cross-community interaction) if we could pin an exchange's custom sidebar to our own so it would always show while logged in across the network. For example, Arqade has a custom screenshot of the week widget that shows above the "Featured on Meta" section:

